# excerpt not showing up

Tags: loop, templates, page-template

I have a custom template for homepage and in it, i want to display excerpt from some category. but not even the simple `the_excerpt()` isn't working. i tried `the_title` and `the_content`, but only title display not content. The following is my code,am i missing something?

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
       <?php the_excerpt();?>
     <?php endwhile;?>
       <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what is the parent theme?

Comment: @iEmanuele TwentyTwelve

Comment: this problem is unbelievable! I tried it with a child theme of TwentyTwelve and I could not replicate the fault. It's working fine. Last question: have you tried to use a your own query to get those posts?

Comment: @iEmanuele my query, what you mean?

Comment: are you sure you dont have content and or excerpt area not blank at the back end ?

Comment: [WordPress Codex - Class Reference - WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: @prince i just checked again. i got a post, a excerpt too.

Comment: echo the_excerpt(); ?

Comment: @iEmanuele which page u used it in? and did you do anything else besides that. note: in back end, my front page is set a static page.

Comment: @iEmanuele My complete code, this is custom-home.php 
`/*
 Template Name: Custom Homepage
 */
get_header();
get_header('home');
`
and my header-home code
`if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 the_content();
 the_excerpt();
 endwhile;
endif;

Comment: did you apply this template to the page on which you are expecting output ? lol

Comment: @prince i think every kid knows that.

Comment: 'i want to display excerpt from some category' - there is nothing in your code so far which would do that; 'my front page is set a static page' - does that page have any content?
'i got a post, a excerpt too' - that does not matter as long as you don't use a custom query.

Comment: @Michael 'i want to display excerpt from some category' , that is for later. isn't that a custom query which i posted above, like `the_loop` and inside that `the_excerpt`? or should be custom query be something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a template file, the standard loop syntax will display only the information about that page( In fact, a template file is no more than a page ). If you want to display some posts you need to run a custom query or to include ( `get_template_part()` ) another template file which normally runs a query for some specific post types or categories.

**Page template example**

```
/*Template name: Example page */
get_header();
    /* The following loop refers to the page object */
    if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        the_title();
        the_excerpt();
    endwhile; endif;

    /* Now you can query for your post using WP_Query Class */
    /* Defining $args array of arguments */
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'post', // maybe page | custom post type | an array of these
        'posts_per_page'    => 6,      // number of items you want to display
    );

    /* Define new $query object to loop through */
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    //Start your custom loop
    if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_excerpt();
    endwhile; else: 
        echo 'No posts found';
    endif;      
 get_footer();
```

Let me know if you get stuck : )

Please, look these from WordPress Codex:

1. [Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates)
2. [Stepping into templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates)
3. [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)
4. [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)
5. [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

**UPDATE**

If you look at my example code you will see an $args array. You can define several options within it please refer to WP_Query docs.
Note: `have_posts()`; and `the_post();` functions don't accept any arguments.
If you want to use the `in_category();` you have to do it in the loop.

Custom loop

```
if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

  if( in_category( 6 ) ){
    //do something
  }else{
    //do something else
  }

endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: it worked! i was only applying  the simple page loop, this is the first time i came across `wp_query_class` and `$args`,never came across that. is that something i can read in codex/wp_query ?, i see its based on oop as it point out to the object -> in array, now what if i want to get posts from a specific category and loop over it as i want to display it in div's and i am unknown by OOP as used.

Comment: yeah! yes sure, i've updated the answer look at the end

Comment: You can tune the $args array to run a query that fits your needs

Comment: It was the same also for me : )

Comment: for some reason my code isn't getting posts from a specific category, this is my code
`if( $query->have_posts(in_category('6')) ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();`
i tried to test it with a category that doesn't exist and it still shows all post. am i missing something?

Comment: @AmmarKhan i've updated the answer.

Comment: does it goes inside the wp_query loop?